# AJAX Function not working? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form thats automatically generated from a PHP while loop.

I want the form to submit data using AJAX and to do that I have the following...

**PHP Form**

```
<div class="user">
    <span>Become friends with '.$row['screen_name'].'</span>
    <form method="POST" action="./create.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$row['user_id'].'" name="follow_id" class="follow_id" />
        <input type="submit" class="follow-submit" value="Get '.$row['credits_offered'].' Credits" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
// Create Friendship AJAX
$(".follow-submit").on("click", function() {

    var follow_id = $(".folow_id").val();

    var dataString = 'follow_id=' + follow_id;
    alert (datastring); return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('.message').html("<p>Friend request sent!</p>");
      }
     });
    return false;

});
```

The problem is that my AJAX, click event doesnt even seem to register and the form continues to post and redirect through to create.php

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: `<span>Become friends with '.$row['screen_name'].'</span>` where are the php tags `<?php ?>` ??

Comment: The PHP is at the top of my page @dianuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code as debug and will see what's wrong

```
success: function($res) {
    console.log($res)
    $('.message').html("<p>Friend request sent!</p>");
  },
error: function($a, $b) {
    console.log($a); 
    console.log($b);
}
```

in your console in firebug at firefox will print errors if exists

Comment: Thanks @AhmedSaad, I receive 'datastring is undefined?' but follow_id value is generated with PHP?

Comment: the problem is 

var follow_id = $(".folow_id").val();

use this

var follow_id = $(".follow_id").val();

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".follow-submit").on("click", function(event) {event.preventDefault();
...
```

Comment: +1 damn faster, was going to suggest `<input type="submit" onsubmit="return false;" class="follow-submit" value="Get '.$row['credits_offered'].' Credits" />`

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping your AJAX function execution by the *first* `return` statement. Remove it and your code should work, also; to prevent the anchor from redirecting to create.php, you'll have to add `event.preventDefault();` within your click handler function. Your code should look like this:

```
// Create Friendship AJAX
$(".follow-submit").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    var follow_id = $(".folow_id").val();

    var dataString = 'follow_id=' + follow_id;
    //alert (datastring); return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('.message').html("<p>Friend request sent!</p>");
      }
     });
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not canceling the submit event. For that, you must have the event as a parameter of your click function and call `preventDefault()` on it. Also, your `return false` is stopping your function right in the middle of it, before you even start your AJAX. You also had a typo, you typed `folow_id` instead of `follow_id` on the second line of your JavaScript. Additionally, a more proper way to do this in my opinion is to use the [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function. Put an ID on your form and do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="user">
    <span>Become friends with '.$row['screen_name'].'</span>
    <form id="follow-form" method="POST" action="./create.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$row['user_id'].'" name="follow_id" class="follow_id" />
        <input type="submit" class="follow-submit" value="Get '.$row['credits_offered'].' Credits" />
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Create Friendship AJAX
$("#follow-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var follow_id = $(".follow_id").val();

    var dataString = 'follow_id=' + follow_id;
    // alert (datastring); return false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {
        $('.message').html("<p>Friend request sent!</p>");
      }
    });

    return false;
});
```